# MySQL LEFT JOINS order, how to understand the correct algorithm

Tags: mysql, optimization, left-join, sql-execution-plan, explain

i'm really confused about how is the correct order to write the LEFT JOINS, in fact if i move one LEFT JOIN from position A to Z, the query is 3x faster, but WHY?
Why the optimizer doens't get the right order by itself?

How can i understand which is the correct order for write a query with N LEFT JOINS?

Example:

**SLOW QUERY:**

```
  SELECT
    c.idRichiesta, i.idImmobile
FROM anagrafica AS cli
INNER JOIN richieste AS c  ON c.idCliente = cli.idCliente
INNER JOIN cat_richieste AS cr ON cr.idRichiesta = c.idRichiesta
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tmr.* FROM (
        (
            SELECT idRichiesta, id_comune, id_frazione, id_nazione
            FROM comuni_richieste
            WHERE idRichiesta = '129563'
        )
        UNION ALL
        (
            SELECT mr.idRichiesta, m.id_comune, m.id_frazione, m.id_nazione
            FROM macro_aree_richieste AS mr
            INNER JOIN macro_aree_dettaglio AS m ON m.id_macro=mr.id_macro
            WHERE mr.idRichiesta = '129563'
        )
    ) AS tmr
    GROUP BY tmr.idRichiesta, tmr.id_comune, tmr.id_frazione
) AS tcr ON tcr.idRichiesta = c.idRichiesta
LEFT JOIN richieste_coordinate_p AS tcrp ON tcrp.idRichiesta = c.idRichiesta
LEFT JOIN richieste_coordinate_c AS tcrc ON tcrc.idRichiesta = c.idRichiesta
INNER JOIN immobili i on i.idCategoria = cr.idCategoria
LEFT JOIN loc_geo as Ltg on Ltg.idImmobile = i.idImmobile
LEFT JOIN stato_mediazione AS s  ON s.id=i.stato_mediazione
WHERE
    i.proposta_in_corso!='2'
    AND (
        (
            (i.Motivazione = 'Vendita')
            AND (  i.Prezzo_Richiesto >= ( c.Prezzo_Min * (100 - 30)/100 ) )
            AND (( ( i.Prezzo_Richiesto * (100 - 30)/100 ) <= ( c.Prezzo_Max * (100 + 30)/100 ) ) or c.Prezzo_Max = 0 )
        )
        OR
        (
            (i.Motivazione ='Affitto/Vendita')
            AND (
                (( i.Prezzo_Richiesto2 >= ( c.Prezzo_Min  * (100 - 30)/100 )) AND ((( i.Prezzo_Richiesto2 * (100 - 30)/100 )  <= ( c.Prezzo_Max * (100 + 30)/100) ) or c.Prezzo_Max=0) AND c.Motivo_Richiesta ='Affitto')
                OR
                (( i.Prezzo_Richiesto >= ( c.Prezzo_Min  * (100 - 30)/100 )) AND ((( i.Prezzo_Richiesto * (100 - 30)/100 )  <= ( c.Prezzo_Max * (100 + 30)/100) ) or c.Prezzo_Max=0)  AND c.Motivo_Richiesta ='Acquisto')
            )
        )
    )
    AND (
        ( i.Citta = tcr.id_comune  AND ((i.ZonaCitta=tcr.id_frazione) OR (tcr.id_frazione = 0) ) )
        OR (
            Ltg.latitudine is not null and Ltg.longitudine is not null
            AND ( tcrp.poligono is not null AND
                ( ST_CONTAINS(tcrp.poligono, POINT(Ltg.latitudine, Ltg.longitudine)) )
                OR ( tcrc.centro is not null AND
                    round (((acos( sin(( X(tcrc.centro) * 0.0174532925)) * sin((Ltg.latitudine * 0.0174532925)) + cos(( X(tcrc.centro) * 0.0174532925)) * cos((Ltg.latitudine * 0.0174532925)) * cos((( Y(tcrc.centro) - Ltg.longitudine) * 0.0174532925)))) * 57.2957795131) * 111.18957696, 2) <= (tcrc.raggio / 1000)
                )
            )
        )
    )
    AND i.Citta>0
    AND (c.idRichiesta = '129563')
    AND (s.id IS NULL OR s.vendibile='si')

GROUP BY i.idImmobile
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
+------+--------------+------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+--+
|  id  | select_type  |      table       |  type  |                     possible_keys                     |     key     | key_len |                  ref                  | rows |              Extra              |  |
+------+--------------+------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+--+
| 1    | PRIMARY      | tcrp             | system | idRichiesta                                           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                  | 0    | const row not found             |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | tcrc             | system | idRichiesta                                           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                  | 0    | const row not found             |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | c                | const  | PRIMARY,idCliente,Prezzo_Max,Motivo_Richiesta         | PRIMARY     | 4       | const                                 | 1    | Using temporary; Using filesort |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | cli              | const  | PRIMARY                                               | PRIMARY     | 4       | const                                 | 1    | Using index                     |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | <derived2>       | ref    | <auto_key1>                                           | <auto_key1> | 4       | const                                 | 0    | Using where                     |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | cr               | ref    | idRichiesta,idCategoria                               | idRichiesta | 4       | const                                 | 9    | Using index condition           |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | i                | ref    | PRIMARY,idProprietario,id_cantiere,codice_agenzia,... | idCategoria | 5       | test_import2.cr.idCategoria     | 2780 | Using where                     |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | Ltg              | ref    | idImmobile                                            | idImmobile  | 4       | test_import2.i.idImmobile       | 1    | Using where                     |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | s                | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                               | PRIMARY     | 4       | test_import2.i.stato_mediazione | 1    | Using where                     |  |
| 2    | DERIVED      | <derived3>       | ALL    | NULL                                                  | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                  | 9    | Using temporary; Using filesort |  |
| 3    | DERIVED      | comuni_richieste | ref    | idRichiesta                                           | idRichiesta | 4       | const                                 | 7    | NULL                            |  |
| 4    | UNION        | mr               | ref    | idRichiesta,id_macro                                  | idRichiesta | 4       | const                                 | 1    | NULL                            |  |
| 4    | UNION        | m                | ref    | id_macro                                              | id_macro    | 4       | test_import2.mr.id_macro        | 1    | NULL                            |  |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union3,4>       | ALL    | NULL                                                  | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                  | NULL | Using temporary                 |  |
+------+--------------+------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+--+
```

**FAST QUERY**:

```
     SELECT
    c.idRichiesta, i.idImmobile
FROM anagrafica AS cli
INNER JOIN richieste AS c  ON c.idCliente = cli.idCliente
INNER JOIN cat_richieste AS cr ON cr.idRichiesta = c.idRichiesta

LEFT JOIN richieste_coordinate_p AS tcrp ON tcrp.idRichiesta = c.idRichiesta
LEFT JOIN richieste_coordinate_c AS tcrc ON tcrc.idRichiesta = c.idRichiesta
INNER JOIN immobili i on i.idCategoria = cr.idCategoria
LEFT JOIN loc_geo as Ltg on Ltg.idImmobile = i.idImmobile
LEFT JOIN stato_mediazione AS s  ON s.id=i.stato_mediazione
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tmr.* FROM (
        (
            SELECT idRichiesta, id_comune, id_frazione, id_nazione
            FROM comuni_richieste
            WHERE idRichiesta = '129563'
        )
        UNION ALL
        (
            SELECT mr.idRichiesta, m.id_comune, m.id_frazione, m.id_nazione
            FROM macro_aree_richieste AS mr
            INNER JOIN macro_aree_dettaglio AS m ON m.id_macro=mr.id_macro
            WHERE mr.idRichiesta = '129563'
        )
    ) AS tmr
    GROUP BY tmr.idRichiesta, tmr.id_comune, tmr.id_frazione
) AS tcr ON tcr.idRichiesta = c.idRichiesta
WHERE
    i.proposta_in_corso!='2'
    AND (
        (
            (i.Motivazione = 'Vendita')
            AND (  i.Prezzo_Richiesto >= ( c.Prezzo_Min * (100 - 30)/100 ) )
            AND (( ( i.Prezzo_Richiesto * (100 - 30)/100 ) <= ( c.Prezzo_Max * (100 + 30)/100 ) ) or c.Prezzo_Max = 0 )
        )
        OR
        (
            (i.Motivazione ='Affitto/Vendita')
            AND (
                (( i.Prezzo_Richiesto2 >= ( c.Prezzo_Min  * (100 - 30)/100 )) AND ((( i.Prezzo_Richiesto2 * (100 - 30)/100 )  <= ( c.Prezzo_Max * (100 + 30)/100) ) or c.Prezzo_Max=0) AND c.Motivo_Richiesta ='Affitto')
                OR
                (( i.Prezzo_Richiesto >= ( c.Prezzo_Min  * (100 - 30)/100 )) AND ((( i.Prezzo_Richiesto * (100 - 30)/100 )  <= ( c.Prezzo_Max * (100 + 30)/100) ) or c.Prezzo_Max=0)  AND c.Motivo_Richiesta ='Acquisto')
            )
        )
    )
    AND (
        ( i.Citta = tcr.id_comune  AND ((i.ZonaCitta=tcr.id_frazione) OR (tcr.id_frazione = 0) ) )
        OR (
            Ltg.latitudine is not null and Ltg.longitudine is not null
            AND ( tcrp.poligono is not null AND
                ( ST_CONTAINS(tcrp.poligono, POINT(Ltg.latitudine, Ltg.longitudine)) )
                OR ( tcrc.centro is not null AND
                    round (((acos( sin(( X(tcrc.centro) * 0.0174532925)) * sin((Ltg.latitudine * 0.0174532925)) + cos(( X(tcrc.centro) * 0.0174532925)) * cos((Ltg.latitudine * 0.0174532925)) * cos((( Y(tcrc.centro) - Ltg.longitudine) * 0.0174532925)))) * 57.2957795131) * 111.18957696, 2) <= (tcrc.raggio / 1000)
                )
            )
        )
    )
    AND i.Citta>0
    AND (c.idRichiesta = '129563')
    AND (s.id IS NULL OR s.vendibile='si')

GROUP BY i.idImmobile
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
+------+--------------+------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+--+
|  id  | select_type  |      table       |  type  |                     possible_keys                     |     key     | key_len |                  ref                  | rows |              Extra              |  |
+------+--------------+------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+--+
| 1    | PRIMARY      | tcrp             | system | idRichiesta                                           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                  | 0    | const row not found             |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | tcrc             | system | idRichiesta                                           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                  | 0    | const row not found             |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | c                | const  | PRIMARY,idCliente,Prezzo_Max,Motivo_Richiesta         | PRIMARY     | 4       | const                                 | 1    | Using temporary; Using filesort |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | cli              | const  | PRIMARY                                               | PRIMARY     | 4       | const                                 | 1    | Using index                     |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | cr               | ref    | idRichiesta,idCategoria                               | idRichiesta | 4       | const                                 | 9    | Using index condition           |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | i                | ref    | PRIMARY,idProprietario,id_cantiere,codice_agenzia,... | idCategoria | 5       | test_import2.cr.idCategoria     | 2780 | Using where                     |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | Ltg              | ref    | idImmobile                                            | idImmobile  | 4       | test_import2.i.idImmobile       | 1    | NULL                            |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | s                | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                               | PRIMARY     | 4       | test_import2.i.stato_mediazione | 1    | Using where                     |  |
| 1    | PRIMARY      | <derived2>       | ref    | <auto_key1>                                           | <auto_key1> | 4       | test_import2.cr.idRichiesta     | 0    | Using where                     |  |
| 2    | DERIVED      | <derived3>       | ALL    | NULL                                                  | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                  | 9    | Using temporary; Using filesort |  |
| 3    | DERIVED      | comuni_richieste | ref    | idRichiesta                                           | idRichiesta | 4       | const                                 | 7    | NULL                            |  |
| 4    | UNION        | mr               | ref    | idRichiesta,id_macro                                  | idRichiesta | 4       | const                                 | 1    | NULL                            |  |
| 4    | UNION        | m                | ref    | id_macro                                              | id_macro    | 4       | test_import2.mr.id_macro        | 1    | NULL                            |  |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union3,4>       | ALL    | NULL                                                  | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                  | NULL | Using temporary                 |  |
+------+--------------+------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+--+
```

As you can see the only difference is the position of LEFT JOIN with the derived query.
But why the second is faster than the fist one? How can see this in the EXPLAIN output?

Feel free to ask me what you need ( index list, create table, etc).
Thanks to all.

Comment: As an aside, while not necessarily incorrect, I find clauses like  `LEFT JOIN s... WHERE (s.id IS NULL OR s.vendibile='si')` very confusing, so try to avoid them if at all possible.

Comment: I tried to remove that condition but the bottleneck remains, i really don't get why there 's this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?  Newer versions will materialize derived tables and discover a suitable index for them as indicated by `<auto_key1>`.  This *sometimes* is a performance benefit.  Older versions will simple re-execute the `SELECT` (and `UNION`, in your case) every time it reaches into the `LEFT JOIN`.

Don't use `LEFT` unless you need it.  Be sure that you want the stuff after `LEFT` even if rows are missing.  (Else drop `LEFT`.)

`ORs` don't optimize well.  See if you can get rid of any of them.

Comment: Mysql 5.6.31.

How can i avoid the LEFT JOIN ? I've two tables to check, geospatial tables, one for the polygon, one for the circle, i need to check if the coordinates inside those tables matches the ones of Ltg.  
Merge 'richieste_coordinate_p' and 'richieste_coordinate_c' in one table?
Two separate query in UNION?  The weird thing is why the position of LEFT JOIN made a big difference in the execution of query? I don't get that point,i really don't know how to find it out!  
Instead  i found that if i delete the geospatial clauses, the query speed up even more.

Comment: `LEFT` says to include even 'missing' rows from the following table(s); without `LEFT`, they are excluded.  And what is the precedence?  `a JOIN b JOIN c` -- does this mean `(a JOIN b) JOIN c` or `a JOIN (b JOIN c)` -- it makes a difference when either of those `JOINs` is a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Sorry @Rick, but what about the optimizer? Why it doesn't chooses the right order of the joins in this case?